# Cause an Aw, Snap! Error in Google Chrome using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to use Javascript to cause/lead to the Aw, Snap! Page in Google Chrome.

I've tried creating really huge elements, and a huge number of them too, but that didn't work... I've also tried some other things, but mainly trying to max out memory.